# Why the concurrent threads limit doesn't works as expected?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Though there are similar issues, I couldn't found any similar examples like the one I got. I really appreciate any help understanding where I got wrong with my implementation.

**What I'm trying to do:**

I have a Main class `Driver`, which can instantiates unknown number of threads. Each thread call a `singleton` class which should simulate a 'fake' file transfer action.
The issue I have is that I need to limit the concurrent transfers to 2 transfers, regardless the number of concurrent requests.

The way I tried to solve my problem is by adding each new `Thread` in a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and managing it by using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOL_SIZE)` to limit the concurrent threads to be 2. for every interation - I poll new thread from the pool using `pool.submit`.

**The Problem I have is my output is like this:**
[Thread1], [Thread1, Thread2], [Thread1, Thread2, Thread3]...

**While it should be:**
[Thread1, Thread2], [Thread3, Thread4]

Why the limitation doesn't work here?

### **My implementation:**

**Copier** - this is my `singleton` class.

```
public class Copier {

    private final int POOL_SIZE = 2;
    private static volatile Copier instance = null;
    private Queue<Reportable> threadQuere = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
    private static FileCopier fileCopier = new FileCopier();

    private Copier() {

    }

    public static Copier getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (Copier.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new Copier();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void fileTransfer(Reportable reportable) {
        threadQuere.add(reportable);

        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOL_SIZE);
        for (int i=0; i < threadQuere.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("This is the " + (i+1) + " thread");
            pool.submit(new CopyThread());
        }
        pool.shutdown();
        try {
            pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**CopyThread** - represend a thread class

```
    public class CopyThread implements Reportable, Runnable {

    private static FileCopier fileCopier = new FileCopier();

    @Override
    public void report(String bitrate) {
        System.out.println(bitrate);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(fileCopier) {
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            long bytes = fileCopier.copyFile();
            long endTime = System.nanoTime();

            double duration = (double)(endTime - startTime) / 1000000000; // get in seconds
            double bytesInMegas = (double) bytes / 1000000;

            report(bytesInMegas + "MB were transferred in " + duration + " seconds");
        }
    }
}
```

**Driver** - my `main` class where do I create all the threads

```
    public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Copier copier = Copier.getInstance();
        CopyThread copyThread1 = new CopyThread();
        CopyThread copyThread2 = new CopyThread();
        CopyThread copyThread3 = new CopyThread();
        CopyThread copyThread4 = new CopyThread();

        copier.fileTransfer(copyThread1);
        copier.fileTransfer(copyThread2);
        copier.fileTransfer(copyThread3);
        copier.fileTransfer(copyThread4);
        int q = 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: You need nothing _but_ a fixed thread pool. No thread management on your own, no singletons either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler solution would be a [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) with 2 permits.

This makes sure that "outside" threads can't bypass the limit either, since your solution expects that the simultaneous tasks are limited by the size of the threadpool.

Your solution uses several concurrency tools when a single one would suffice. Your DCL singleton is a bit outdated too.

Comment: can you provide a simple example?
p.s. - why my singleton is outdated? what would you suggest instead? enum?

Comment: Yes, enum. It's been the standard way for quite some time now. As for `Semaphore`, there's plenty of examples. It's essentially like `synchronized` except you get to choose the amount of allowed threads.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is probably fine here (although a bit weird). You are printing the thread numbers before submiting, what you need to do is put print in a run method, and you will see that everything works fine. The print are all gonna go off normally, because the area where you are using print has nothing to do with Executors. There is more problems with your code, but I think you did all that just for testing/learning so that's why it's like that.

In that case, like I said, put prints in the run method (you can use some static variable in CopyThread class for counting threads). Your output will be something like 2 prints about thread numbers (1 and 2), 2 prints about how long transfer took and then prints about thread 3 and 4 (I say probably, because we are working with threads, can't be sure of anything) - all this at the step 4 ofcourse, when your `fileTransfer` submits 4 runnables. Your singleton is outdated, because it uses double checked locking, which is wrong on multithreaded machine, check this: [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074979/java-concurrency/double-checked-locking--clever--but-broken.html). That's not ruining your program so worry about it later. About everything else (weird queue usage, `fileTransfer` method making new threads pools etc.) like I said, it's probably for learning, but if it's not - your queue may as well be deleted, you are using it only for counting and counting like this could be done with some counter variable, and your `fileTransfer` method should just submit new runnable to pool (which would be instance variable) to transfer a file, not create pool and submit few runnables, it's kinda anty-intuitive.

Edit: check this, I put all in `Cat.java` for simplicity, changed some things that I had to change (I don't have `FileCopier` class etc., but answer to your problem is here):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
class Copier {
    private final int POOL_SIZE = 2;
    private static volatile Copier instance = null;
    private Copier() {

    }
    public static Copier getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (Copier.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new Copier();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void fileTransfer() {
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOL_SIZE);
        for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
            pool.submit(new CopyThread());
        }
        pool.shutdown();
        try {
            pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class CopyThread implements Runnable {
    private static int counter = 0;
    public void report(String bitrate) {
        System.out.println(bitrate);
    }
    Object obj = new Object();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(obj) {
            System.out.println("This is the " + (++counter) + " thread");
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            long bytes = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<100000; i++)
                bytes+=1;
            long endTime = System.nanoTime();

            double duration = (double)(endTime - startTime) / 1000000000; // get in seconds
            double bytesInMegas = (double) bytes / 1000000;

            report(bytesInMegas + "MB were transferred in " + duration + " seconds");
        }
    }
}

public class Cat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Copier copier = Copier.getInstance();
        copier.fileTransfer();
    }
}
```

Comment: The print movement doesn't have anything to do with the bad implementation I have. it's always run like:
t1, t1-t2, t1-t2-t3.o.. 10 times over all, while it should run:
t1-t2, t3-t4

Comment: That's because you do it like that, `for (int i=0; i < threadQuere.size(); i++) {`, query size first time is 1, then it's 2, then 3 and 4. You can just do `for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {` here and it will do t1-t2-t3-t4 right away, then in main `copier.fileTransfer(copyThread1);` only one time, not four times (different runnable as parameter doesn't matter here, you don't do anything with it).

Comment: No dude, it won't work either...
but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Check my post above, I edited your code to show you what I meant, and like I said, it works like it should. (everything in Cat.java if you want to check)